# Removing deprecated functionality from a library

Tags: java, api, language-agnostic, deprecated

Say I have a method in my api called `foo`. In the next version of my api, I would like to replace this method with `bar`. How would I go about doing so?

A couple of options are:

1) Just remove `foo`. In the Release Notes, state that this method has been replaced by `bar`. This will break clients when they try to build using my new library, but who cares? They will just have to fix themselves.

2) Mark `foo` deprecated and in the Release Notes, state that `bar` should be preferred. Log warnings when the deprecated method is called. Then in the next version, remove `foo` altogether. This gives clients a small window of warning.

What would you do?

Comment: See this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338216/what-is-the-best-practice-to-remove-support-for-a-feature/4338303#4338303

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do 2, then 1.

During your "small window of warning" make it clear to your clients that `bar` is all the rage, and ensure that all (or, at your discretion, most) no longer depend on `foo` before removing the dead weight from your library. This way, your clients can go to the trouble at their own convenience, rather than being forced to by a binary break.

Of course, as David mentioned, you'll need to use your own judgment based on the size of your userbase. If this is a small library only used by a couple of close contacts, it may well be more effective to just make the change, but it's *good form* to mark as deprecated.

Answer (score 5):

Definitely do 2.

1 above doesn't just affect compile-time, but also if your library jar is replaced by the end user, causing run-time errors.

Comment: And, depending on how wide your deployment base is, you may want more than a "small window of warning", so you might want to go through multiple releases (with increasing strident warnings :-) before completely removing the legacy function.

Comment: @David: Java's standard library, as an example, has never removed anything, even the parts marked Deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Your seconds choice is standard dealing with method replacement.

Answer (score 0):

If the client programs are under my control, and if I have good test coverage for them, then I switch the clients to the new signature and remove the old one.  Otherwise I deprecate the old signature.